# Fastest way to process XML insert in InfluxDB

Tags: xml, insert, influxdb

long story short, i need to insert a lot of XML files in my influxDB database.

I will be using Grafana dashboard to review the datas. And i planned to use Telegraf witt plugin to make the data collection, but i now realize that i can't find any plugin capable of processing XML files. So i was wondering what is therefore the best (fastest & simplest) way to input my data ? It will probably be to parse the XML and use the HTTP API right ?

I'm asking because i'm totally new to this.

Also here is the whole situation for a better understanding if someone wants to bother reading.

We have time-based data coming from a lot of sensors, every quarter or every hour (for now). The data are sent through email as XML files. I get the XML files in the emails every quarter. Then i parsed and inserted them into MySQL, but obviously MySQL didn't hold the charge.

The plan was to use Grafana + InfluxDB to get all these datas, and now i realize i still need to parse these XML to insert them, and pretty quyickly...

Please if you have any idea, i just need help right now...

Comment: Influxdb is a time series database. You can't insert `XML` data into it directly. You'll have to parse the content and make `HTTP` calls to insert the values `.

Comment: That is what i understood so far. I'm just wondering how exactly i will parse those XML and make the HTTP calls. For now i'm going to try with Node JS. Also, i'm really wondering how much HTTP calls i should do at the same time. I mean, i could have something like 200 XML at the same moment, each containing thousands of line, so shoud i make one request per line, per 100 lines ? what is the best way to process the whole thing without making influxDB or Node JS crash ? 

Also, if you think there is a better language / way to do it than with Node, tell me, i went into it more or less randomly.